# Random walk on a binary ring with switching of states

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider a ring containing N sites, each of which can either be 'on' or 'off', with equal probability. At $t=0$, the sites are either all 'on' or all 'off'. If we allow each site to switch states (i.e. an 'on' state becomes 'off') at a rate $\mu$ and the possibility of each state to replace one of its neighbour's at a rate $\lambda$, how does the probability that $k$ sites are 'on' vary as a function of time, $t$?

Prior to doing any calculations, we can consider the limits of the problem. If $\mu >> \lambda$ then we will have a distribution that rapidly drifts towards a binomial distribution with $p=0.5$ and $n=N$. Conversely, if $\mu << \lambda$ the distribution will stay as that at $t=0$, with

$$P(k) =
\begin{cases}
0.5,  & \text{if $k$ is 0 or N} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

If we initially consider a single site that is 'on' at $t=0$, we essentially have a 2-state system with a switching rate $\mu$ and initial conditions $p(t=0)=1$ the probability that the site is 'on' is:
$$p(t) = \frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-2\mu t})$$

We now consider N sites that are able to switch states (for now, ignoring the possibility of replacement) but are all either 'on' or 'off' at $t=0$. Essentially we have a sum of two binomial distributions (due to the symmetry between 'on' and 'off'):
$$P(k) = \frac{1}{2} \binom{N}{k} \frac{1}{2^N} \left( 
(1+e^{-2\mu t})^{k}(1-e^{-2\mu t})^{N-k} + 
(1-e^{-2\mu t})^{k}(1+e^{-2\mu t})^{N-k}
\right)$$

Equivalently:
$$P(k) = \frac{1}{2} \binom{N}{k} e^{-N\mu t} \left( 
\cosh^{k}{\mu t}\sinh^{N-k}{\mu t} + 
\sinh^{k}{\mu t}\cosh^{N-k}{\mu t}
\right)$$

However, I am unsure of the next steps required to incorporate the replacement of neighbouring states into this probability distribution.

EDIT 1:

On reflection, the above approach is not the best way to solve this problem. Rather than consider the number of 'on' sites as our variable of interest, we should focus on the unique states. As an example, consider the case $N=4$. We have 16 separate states (although there is a level of redundancy between states, so there are actually 6 unique states, however I'm not entirely sure how to take into account this multiplicity). We now have a true Markov chain, as the transition probability is only dependent on the current state. I believe that we then have the transition matrix, $T$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
  8l & m & m & m & m & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  m + 2 l & 4 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & m & m + l & 0 & m + l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  m + 2 l & 0 & 4 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + l & m + l & 0 & 0 & m & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  m + 2 l & 0 & 0 & 4 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + l & m + l & m & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  m + 2 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 l & m & 0 & m + l & 0 & m + l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & m + 2 l & m + 2 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + 2 l & m + 2 l & 0 & 
   0 & 0\\
  0 & m + l & 0 & 0 & m + l & 0 & 4 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + l & m + l & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & m + l & 0 & m + l & 0 & 0 & 4 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + l & 0 & m + l & 0\\
  0 & m + l & 0 & m + l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 l & 0 & 0 & m + l & 0 & m + l & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & m + l & m + l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 l & 0 & m + l & 0 & 0 & m + l & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & m + 2 l & m + 2 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + 2 l & 
   m + 2 l & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m & 0 & 0 & m + l & m + l & 0 & 4 l & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + 2 l \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m & m + l & m + l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 l & 0 & 0 & m + 2 l \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + l & 0 & m + l & 0 & m & 0 & 0 & 4 l & 0 & m + 2 l \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m + l & 0 & m + l & m & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 l & m + 2 l \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m & m & m & m & 8l\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
We then know that $P_k(t)=P_k(0)e^T$ where $e^T$ is the matrix exponential of T. How do I generalise this process to N states?

Comment: instead of the state space being $N$-bit vectors (i.e. size $2^N$), you can reduce it to all possible ways to break up the ring into contiguous chunks of same-state segments.  i.e. sequences $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_k)$ representing $a_1$ ON states, followed by $a_2$ OFF states, then $a_3$ ON states, etc.  thus $k$ is even and $\sum a_j = N$, and you can further reduce by rotational symmetry.  then you need to add the special all-ON and all-OFF states.  for $N=4$ i think you just need 6 states: all-ON, all-OFF, $(3,1), (2,2), (1,3), (1,1,1,1)$.

Comment: [cont'd] you will need a bit of care to write the transition matrix, but it can be done.  e.g. $(3,1) \rightarrow (1,1,1,1)$ at rate $\mu$ (the middle ON site in the string-of-$3$ switches).  i dont know how much smaller this state space is (asymptotically) compared to $2^N$, but this is the smallest representation i can think of that captures the (IMHO crucial) info about the boundaries between same-state segments, as these affect how many $\lambda$s actually change the no. of ON sites.